# Does anybody know which Rabbi wrote ,something along lines of, "It's more important to be healthy than do a Mitzva"?

Tags: halacha, health-safety-shmira, psych-mentalhealth

I know that the Rambam writes its a Positive Commandment to take care of your health etc. *I'm not referring to* *that*. This seems to go above that saying that it is **more** important to take care of your health than perform a(n other) Mitzva- I believe it was written in a Sefer by a well known early Acharon. I definitely heard it or saw it somewhere but I can't remember where.

If anyone knows I'd really appreciate it.